# How To Access Polymer Custom Element From Callback

Tags: polymer

I need to access the custom element and call its method from the click event callback.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            ...
        </style>
        <ul id="my_data"></ul>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            dataSelected: function(selectedText) {
                //...
            },

            setData: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        // how can I call dataSelected() from here?
                    });
                    li.innerText = data[i];
                    this.$.my_data.appendChild(li);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

How can I call the custom element's `dataSelected()` method from the callback?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `bind` to attach a `this` context to any function, so:

```
   li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      this.dataSelected(e.target.innerText);
    }.bind(this));
```

http://jsbin.com/xorex/4/edit

But you can make things easier by using more Polymer sugaring. For example, you can publish data and use the observation system, like so:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="data">
...
    data: [], // type hint that data is an array
...
    dataChanged: function() { // formerly setData
```

http://jsbin.com/xorex/5/edit

Also, you can use the built-in event system instead of `addEventListener`

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="data">
  ...
  <ul id="my_data" on-tap="{{dataTap}}"></ul>
  ...
    dataTap: function(e) { // `tap` supports touch and mouse
      if (e.target.localName === 'li') {
        this.dataSelected(e.target.textContent);
      }
    }
```

http://jsbin.com/xorex/6/edit

But the biggest win is using `<template repeat>` instead of creating elements in JavaScript. At that point, the complete element can look like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="data">
<template>

  <ul id="my_data">
    <template repeat="{{item in data}}">
      <li on-tap="{{dataTap}}">{{item}}</li>
    </template>
  </ul>

</template>
<script>

  Polymer('my-element', {
    data: [],

    dataTap: function(e) {
      console.log('dataSelected: ' + e.target.textContent);
    }
  });

</script>
</polymer-element>
```

http://jsbin.com/xorex/7/edit

Answer (score 4):

You could insert `element = this;` at the beginning of your setData() function and call `element.dataSelected();` in the event handler.

But i think for what you want to achieve, you'd better use a repeat template ([Iterative templates](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html)) and a direct binding to your click handler function ([Declarative event mapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping)).