# Passing correct callback in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use a `core-xhr` to call a URL and set the response to a variable, like this

```
this.$.xhr.request({url:"<theURL>", method:'POST', body: "<xmldata>", callback : this.processXML});
[ .. ]
processXML : function(response) { 
  this.data = response; //its basically window.data = response
  console.log(this);
}
```

As specified in my comment, `this` is not referring to the polymer element in question rather it points to `window`.

Please advice the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I already knew the answer.

```
this.$.xhr.request({url:"<theURL>", method:'POST', body: "<xmldata>", callback : this.processXML.bind(this)});
```

Using `bind(this)` will bind `this` to any function being called.

More at: [How To Access Polymer Custom Element From Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713712/how-to-access-polymer-custom-element-from-callback)