# Instantiate polymer-element only when needed?

Tags: javascript, polymer

It seems that even if I have the `<template id="{{someCondition}}">...</template>` it will still notify all the lifecycle events of that `polymer-element`. How would I go about if I have one Login-screen and only want to instantiate the rest of the `polymer-elements` when a login is successful?

Is there some built-in way to do this (only instantiate and trigger life-cycle events on some condition) or do I have to instantiate them by using Javascript when a login is successful?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is built-in way. It's called [dynamic HTML imports](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/helpers.html#using-dynamic-html-imports)
Here is example [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0j964CFdJpAdVXjhNsp?p=info)

In the template, if you are passing some data, warp dynamically imported elements in a conditional template to ensure that data binding will happen after the element is registered.

```
 <template if="{{dynamic_element_registered}}" >
  <my-dynamic_element categories_globals={{categories_globals}}>
    I'm just an unknown element.
  </my-dynamic_element>
</template>
```

In  the prototype:

```
 dynamic_load: function() {
      console.log('dynamic_load');
      Polymer.import(['my-dynamic_element.html'], function() {

        this.dynamic_element_registered = true;

      }.bind(this));
  },
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm after! Once I've tried it out and it works as expected I will mark this as the answer! Thank you! Another question though: what is the purpose of the ".bind(this)" ?

Comment: bind(this) explanation: "You can use bind to attach a this context to any function" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713712/how-to-access-polymer-custom-element-from-callback

Comment: I can only find documentation for this on Polymer 0.5.  Is there a 1.0 version of same?